# Bootstrap 4 navbar hamburger always at least partially filled

Tags: bootstrap-4

In Bootstrap 4 is it possible to do the following (without much customisation)?:

- The hamburger is always displayed in the navbar.
- The hamburger would always contain certain options such as logout.
- Other options would be displayed in the navbar.
- On shrinking the screen the other options in the navbar would disappear from the navbar and appear in the hamburger.

An example of this behaviour is [the-dots.com](http://the-dots.com). The hamburger always displays 6 options, but on shrinking the page the navbar options get added to the hamburger.

Comment: "**In Bootstrap 4 is it possible to do the following?**".. not really with Bootstrap out-of-the-box, but just about anything's possible with CSS&JS. However, this question is too broad for SO. Please **[read how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** and 
[what not to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) ***before*** asking. 
It's expected that you **make an effort to solve the problem *before* asking**. You'll also need to include a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates or reproduces the issue **specifically** 
described in the question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've now added "without much customisation" to the initial question.